# java.util.logging not working in Gwt and Glassfish

Tags: java, gwt, logging, glassfish

I'm working on create gwt application and deploy it on glassfish. I used java.util.logging for logging, however it seems to not work as I cannot find any log in server.log. I already put  into .gwt.xml, but it doesn't help. Can anyone let me know what I should do in order to store logs in server.log? Thanks a lot.

L

Answer (score 1):

Refer tohttps://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging  if you are using GWT 2.4 and above. You can use gwt- log lib if you are using older gwt.